# my CID program the best way to backup database locally?

Tags: java, mysql, database

-my Cid program written in java code ..

-my Cid program can add cases and modify them ..

-my program connected to 2 databases  1 is the primary and 1 is the secondary ..

- my data base  is sqllite ..

-the cases that i insert have content(Text) and photos(image) for each case ..

-when i insert the data i insert it in the primary database first then in the secondary database .. same when i modify ..

so my questions is how can i make sure that is every case that i insert is added into both databases ?? same for modify .. ??

and what i do if the program closed before he insert it to secondary database (for example if the program crushed or by miss click closed ) how can i fix the missing case in the secondary database

============================

i am still new here if i didn't clear any part please tell me what i have tell you more about my program .. thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [two-phase-commit protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)

During distributed transaction that is the only secure answer.

Please also consider to take a deep look at  [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_txns003.htm#ADMIN12222) about it